# la meilleure traduction de 'braindead'

Tags: traduction

'braindead' en anglais est un adjectif qui peut être utilisé de façon informelle pour dire: extrêmement bête, mais aussi, quelque chose qui ne nécessite aucune pensée, compétence ou effort. Par exemple, 'he is braindead' signifie qu'il est extrêmement stupide, cependant, 'the exam was completely braindead' signifie qu'on a trouvé que l'examen était très facile, tellement facile et nécessitant aucune réflexion. Pour l'instant, je pense que la meilleur traduction est 'débile'. Prenez l'example:

Anglais: 'Well, for the moment, I'm only really doing braindead stuff, but since I'm an intern, I guess that's pretty common.'
Français: 'Pour l'instant, je fais que des choses (débiles ?), mais vu que je suis stagiaire, je suppose que c'est assez fréquent.'

Attention, il y également un sens d'ennui ici. C'est pas simplement très facile, c'est tellement facile qu'on s'ennuie.

Merci d'avance pour votre aide (:

---

Braindead in english is an adjective that can be used informally to say extremely stupid, but also, something that requires no thought, skill, or effort. For example, 'he is braindead' means that he's extremely stupid, but, 'the exam was completely braindead' means that you found the exam very easy, so easy that it didn't require any thought. I think the best I've got right now is 'débile'. Take the example:

Anglais: 'Well, for the moment, I'm only really doing braindead stuff, but since I'm an intern, I guess that's pretty common.' Français: 'Pour l'instant, je fais que des choses (débiles ?), mais vu que je suis stagiaire, je suppose que c'est assez fréquent.'

Be careful, because there's also a sense of boredom in the word. It's not just easy, it's so easy that you're bored and can feel your brain turning to mush.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: rem : c'est peut-être fait exprès, mais on devrait dire "je NE fais que des choses débiles"

Answer (score 3):

***Débile*** me paraît pas mal comme traduction.

> Pour l'instant, je fais que des trucs débiles, mais comme je suis stagiaire, ça doit être normal.

> L'examen était complètement débile.

When talking about a person, you can also say ***neuneu***.

As qoba suggested, there is also the adjective ***teubé***, which is more recent.

Comment: On peut dire aussi *[complétement] teubé*, qui a aussi la connotation d'ennuyeux

Comment: @qoba Added, thanks.

Comment: Parmi les possibles selon DeepL : "I'm only really doing braindead stuff" → « Trucs de malade mental/fou/bourgeois/génie/… — Choses sans esprit/cervelle/intérêt/importance/âme/lendemain/intelligence/… Histoires de décérébration/mort-nés/… » | "A braindead guy" → « Un mec en panne de cerveau/méninges/décodeurs/… — Un homme en 'sursis mental'/'fin de vie'/'perte de cervelle' … Le choix est difficile, et celui proposé n’est pas complet !

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, il y a quantité de traductions possibles suivant le contexte. *Débile* va bien pour un examen je trouve. Aucune des traductions de Deepl n'est très séduisante, à part *panne de cerveau* qui est pas mal du tout. *Truc de malade mental* me semble un contresens. On dit ça de quelque chose d'hallucinant, pas d'ennuyeux et trop facile.

Comment: teubé est le verlan de bête, je pense que c'est trop familier dans le texte de l'OP. Débile reste à mon sens la meilleure solution, éventuellement au superlatif (débilissime) si on veut insister.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne connais pas d'expression idiomatique française qui représente bien cette notion, mais une expression d'un de mes anciens profs de maths m'est restée :
**encéphalogramme plat**

E.g. :

> Et là vous en arrivez au développement, qui se fait à ***encéphalogramme plat***

Je pense que c'est probablement plus lourd à utiliser que *braindead*, mais si ça peut donner des idées à d'autres personnes.